# Movement on canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So, I switched from using Phaser to making the game with Canvas elements.

I got the map to appear, and a placeholder spritesheet implemented, but the movement only works on which direction the sprite faces.

Here's my code:

```
Player.prototype.checkDirection = function () {
var newDrawX = this.drawX,
    newDrawY = this.drawY,//draw specific specific points on x and y coordinates
    newMoveX = this.moveX,
    newMoveY = this.moveY;
    obstacleCollision = false;
if (this.isUpKey) {
    newDrawY -= this.speed;
    this.moveY -= 35;
    this.srcX = 48; //Facing North
    this.srcY = 72;
} else if (this.isDownKey) {
    newDrawY += this.speed;
    this.moveY += 35;
    this.srcX = 48; //Facing South
    this.srcY = 1;
} else if (this.isRightKey) {
    newDrawX += this.speed;
    this.moveX += 31;
    this.srcX = 48; //Facing East
    this.srcY = 36;
} else if (this.isLeftKey) {
    newDrawX -= this.speed;
    this.moveX -= 31;
    this.srcX = 48; //Facing West
    this.srcY = 108;
}

if (!obstacleCollision && !outOfBounds(this, newDrawX, newDrawY)) {
    this.drawX = newDrawX;
    this.drawY = newDrawY;
};
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

Just removing this:

`&& !outOfBounds(this, newDrawX, newDrawY)`

Was enough to allow character movement. I fixed my own problem!